# Setting environment variables in PHP for further use in Windows batch command

Tags: php, batch-file, environment-variables

The story is like this:

- After running a JUnit test campaign, I
  run a php script to get the variables
  $testsOK and $testsFailed.
- In the same php script I have to add to environment variables "OK" and
  "FAILED" the numbers that I obtained
  just before in the same script. I
  used putenv, $_ENV["OK"]= ... even
  apache_setenv("OK",$testsOK), which
  of course does not work since I do
  not have a webserver, I only use PHP
  CLI.
- I will have to use these environment variables "OK" and "FAILED" in
  windows batch command after the
  script was run.

On the putenv page on php.net (http://php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php) someone says that:
"putenv/getenv, $_ENV, and phpinfo(INFO_ENVIRONMENT) are three completely distinct environment stores. doing putenv("x=y") does not affect $_ENV; but also doing $_ENV["x"]="y" likewise does not affect getenv("x"). And neither affect what is returned in phpinfo()."

Therefore, none of these methods will help me. My question is: should I drop this method and try with another language? :-) or is there a way that I'm missing.

I would very much appreciate your help.
Anca

Comment: You cannot set environment variables in another process and have them retained in the parent shell. That works nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wrap the invocation in a script, the PHP would return via stdout the values to be set; the script would then capture this output into the appropiate environment variables.

A very simplified version would be something like this.

```
@echo off
runtestcampaign
for /f %%a in ('php myscript.php') do (
  set OK=%%a
  set Fail=%%b
)
restofbat
```